# thinking-sphinx index minimum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have a Product & Price models, where:

```
class Product < AR::Base
  has_many :prices # there are several types of prices, e.g. for guests, users et.c.
```

I want to index and sort products by price values, belonging to this product and exact price_type.

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :product, with: :active_record do
  indexes name
  indexes k1c
  indexes catalogue_code
  indexes created_at, sortable: true
  indexes prices(:value), as: :price, sortable: true # TODO

  has :category_id
  has :brand_id
  has :kind_cd
  has :price_id
end
```

After `rake ts:rebuild I get that`

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `type' for nil:NilClass
/home/asiniy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@zhivojoffice/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/attribute/type.rb:64:in `type_from_database'
/home/asiniy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@zhivojoffice/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/attribute/type.rb:17:in `type'
/home/asiniy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@zhivojoffice/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/attribute.rb:4:in `type'
/home/asiniy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@zhivojoffice/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/attribute/sphinx_presenter.rb:30:in `sphinx_type'
/home/asiniy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@zhivojoffice/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/attribute/sphinx_presenter.rb:18:in `collection_type'
/home/asiniy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@zhivojoffice/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/sql_source.rb:96:in `block in append_presenter_to_attribute_array'
/home/asiniy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@zhivojoffice/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/sql_source.rb:93:in `each'
/home/asiniy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@zhivojoffice/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/sql_source.rb:93:in `append_presenter_to_attribute_array'
/home/asiniy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@zhivojoffice/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/sql_source.rb:132:in `prepare_for_render'
/home/asiniy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@zhivojoffice/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/sql_source.rb:65:in `render'
/home/asiniy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@zhivojoffice/gems/riddle-1.5.10/lib/riddle/configuration/index.rb:29:in `block in render'
/home/asiniy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@zhivojoffice/gems/riddle-1.5.10/lib/riddle/configuration/index.rb:29:in `collect'
/home/asiniy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@zhivojoffice/gems/riddle-1.5.10/lib/riddle/configuration/index.rb:29:in `render'
/home/asiniy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@zhivojoffice/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/core/index.rb:53:in `render'
/home/asiniy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@zhivojoffice/gems/riddle-1.5.10/lib/riddle/configuration.rb:41:in `block in render'
/home/asiniy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@zhivojoffice/gems/riddle-1.5.10/lib/riddle/configuration.rb:41:in `collect'
/home/asiniy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@zhivojoffice/gems/riddle-1.5.10/lib/riddle/configuration.rb:41:in `render'
/home/asiniy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@zhivojoffice/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/configuration.rb:88:in `render'
/home/asiniy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@zhivojoffice/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/configuration.rb:94:in `block in render_to_file'
/home/asiniy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@zhivojoffice/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/configuration.rb:94:in `render_to_file'
/home/asiniy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@zhivojoffice/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/rake_interface.rb:13:in `configure'
/home/asiniy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@zhivojoffice/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/rake_interface.rb:24:in `index'
/home/asiniy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@zhivojoffice/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.0/lib/thinking_sphinx/tasks.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/asiniy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@zhivojoffice/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/asiniy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@zhivojoffice/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => ts:rebuild => ts:index
```

Need I write a raw SQL query or there is another method?

**UPD**

Analogue sql query for get a one price (after that I want to order by price):

```
SELECT "prices".* FROM "prices" WHERE "prices"."product_id" = $1 AND "prices"."price_type_id" = 1 LIMIT 1
```

My prices model. Quantity of price_types are about 5 and changes very seldom.

```
class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :price_type, :value, :product, presence: true
  validates :price_type, uniqueness: { scope: :product }
  validates :value, numericality: { greater_than: 0.0 }

  belongs_to :price_type
  belongs_to :product
end
```

Comment: Show us your `prices` model, please.

Comment: @Daiku see below UPD section...

Else I little rewrite my question.

Comment: What's the full index definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of things to note here.

Firstly: attributes are a better fit for sorting (they're sortable by their very nature)... but yes, if you want to sort by the minimum price, then you're going to need a SQL snippet for that:

```
has 'MIN(prices.value)', as: :price, type: :float
```

You will also need to ensure you're referring to the `prices` association either in a separate field or attribute, or explicitly in a call to `join`, to ensure the table is actually part of the joins in the generated SQL query:

```
join prices
```

However, the error you're seeing is unrelated to this - it's complaining that it can't determine the type of an attribute because the specified column doesn't exist. I'm pretty certain this is from your `price_id` attribute, which should probably go through the `prices` association:

```
has prices.id, as: :price_ids
```

Making this change has the added bonus of ensuring the SQL join exists for the `prices` table, and so you don't need the `join prices` line in your index definition.

Comment: And else one question. How can I specify type of price for indices? It seems I'll use both price & price type in some filterings.

Comment: I'm not sure what the cause of that error is - I'll need to see the full stack trace. As for searching by price type, do you want all Products with a specific price type? Or something else?

Comment: don't worry about first error. Solved by myself, just a typo. What about next question?

Comment: I found that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19157235/search-by-year-with-thinking-sphinx

Is there any better solution?

Comment: I'm going to need more detail on how you want to search across Products and/or Prices.

Comment: Perhaps it's best to post this as another question?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51080/discussion-between-asiniy-and-pat)